# mongodb query optimize: selecting specific column or all columns which query will be faster

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express

I am wondering to find the optimize and faster way of getting data from mongodb. i have find query which returns all the records with all the fields on the other hand am using find query which returns all records but selective fields which query will be more faster ?

Comment: ofcourse which are returning only selected fields, always makes query which return whatever you wants, not all records

Comment: It depends upon the size of the document with all fields and the size with limited number of fields. And, the number of documents returned. The network over which the data is returned is a factor.  These are the main factors (in this case), I think.